# issue with npm updates on ubuntu

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm, bower

I am using node-v0.10.25 and npm 1.3.24 on ubuntu 12.  I am trying to install bower but getting the following error with either of the commands listed below:

```
npm install bower 
npm install -g bower
sudo npm install bower
```

**Error**

```
19560 error code EPEERINVALID
```

Any ideas on fixing it will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `npm@1.3.24` is over a year old. Could you try [upgrading](https://github.com/npm/npm/wiki/Troubleshooting#upgrading-on-nix-osx-linux-etc)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was thinking of upgrading node and npm (which I will in any case) but using the following works as of now:

```
sudo npm install -g bower
```